# Easy way of using excel vba in access vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a fairly big piece of excel vba code that I need to run. The problem is, that I need to start it from Access and the company security does not allow the starting of makros from an external trigger.

So I can start the excel code when in excel but I need to basically have to open the spreadsheet and have access do the same work that the excel code does.

Can I just copy the code and have it all run in Access and just somehow tell it that "ActiveChart" and "WorkSheets("XY")" are within Excel file "Z"?

Thanks

Kaz

Comment: Access VBA can run any Excel VBA. You'll just have to call the appropriate objects and constants. Personally, I try to never run anything in Excel. As a relational database, Access has a more robust application and automation environment with a SQL engine, GUI interface builder, and reporting generator, much better tool than a flatfile spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an instance of Excel in your Access VBA:

*You will need to set a reference to the Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library*

```
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim wrkBook As Excel.Workbook

Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
Set wrkBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")

wrkBook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Activate

With wrkBook.ActiveSheet
```

.... etc.

Comment: No reference needed if you use late binding (especially when users can have different versions): `Dim appExcel as Object  Set appExcel=CreateObject("Excel.Application")`